# Local storage not applying to remember the last user input for the class toggle

Tags: javascript, storage, local

Local storage value saved but how to use the saved local storage used. I tried creating a function apply but the class is not applying

```
document.querySelectorAll("#abc, #xyz").forEach(btn => {  
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const e = document.querySelectorAll(".dog,.cat, #abc, #xyz");
        e.forEach(el => {
            el.classList.toggle("red");
var xyz = document.getElementById("xyz").className;
localStorage.setItem("vovo", xyz);
        });   
    }); 
})

function apply(){
 var xy = localStorage.getItem('vovo');
 if (xy) {
    var single = document.querySelectorAll(".dog,.cat, #abc, #xyz");
    single.forEach(el => {
        el.classList.add(xy);
        });  
 }
};
```

Comment: Instead of asking “how to” questions, you should show us what you have tried, and ask a _specific_ question about what the problem with it was.

Comment: sori about it.. updated to what i tried

Comment: which input ? And how you'll use it later ?

Comment: everytime a user click on .dog,.cat, #abc, #xyz, the class/value "red" will be saved to local storage.. so when they revisit, the last saved class/value will be applied

Comment: @Origami added an answer, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality logic :

- when a `button` is pressed we check if it has the `red` class (as all the elements, `button`s and the other `div`s, will receive the `red` class at some point).

  - if it has that class then it will be toggled (it will be removed from all the `button`s and the other `div`s) thus the `localStorage` will store something like *"No the elements don't have the red class"*.
  - if it doesn't has it the it will be toggled (it will be added to all the `button`s and the other `div`s) thus the `localStorage` will store something like *"Yes the elements have the red class"*.
  - basically, the `localStorage` will store `'0'` if the class isn't applied, `'1'` if the class is applied.
- now, when the page gets refreshed, we check if the `localStorage` item that stores the `red` class' state is there (not `null`) and has the value of `'1'` then apply that class to all the elements (the `button`s and the other `div`s).
- remove the item that holds the `red` class' state from the `localStorage`.

Here's the update `JavaScript` code :

> Sorry for everyone as I can't make a live demo using SO's snippets as the `localStorage` can't be reached because the code is sandboxed.
>
> Anyway, here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Thabet_Sakhraoui/pen/eqLJmY) demo illustrating the required functionality.

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('.dog,.cat, #abc, #xyz');

/** when the page finishes loading **/
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    /** check if the 'red' class was applied **/
    applied = window.localStorage.getItem('class-applied') === '0' ? false:true;
  /** remove "class-applied" item from the localStorage **/
  window.localStorage.removeItem('class-applied');
  /** if the "red" class was applied just apply it on document load **/
  applied && els.forEach(el => el.classList.add('red'));
});

els.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    /** store the "red" class' state : '1' means it is applied, '0' means it isn't apllied **/
    window.localStorage.setItem(
      'class-applied',
      !btn.classList.contains('red') ? '1' : '0'
    );
    els.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('red'));
  });
});
```

> The above code should be placed just before `</body>`.

Comment: thank you once again ths. for all those who helped, i thank you. Ive a learning disability due to a brain injury so i really try. If ive offended any, im sorry

Comment: you're welcome at any time ! I wish speedy recovery for you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

just use the following syntax:

```
localStorage.setItem('myLocalStorageVariable', 'myValue');
```

If you want to read the value instead:

```
localStorage.getItem('myLocalStorageVariable')
```